# Using DirectoryIndex is not changing index in Apache

Tags: php, html, apache, indexing

This is the change I made in in the httpd.conf file to make index.php the home page

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

most answers say to look for a .htaccess file, but a search does not yield any of those files in the directory

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Changes in httpd.conf won't take affect until you do.  Secondly if you have an index.html in the directory then it will take precedence. Reverse the order in your directive or rename index.html to something else.

Comment: Apache has been restarted and index.html has been removed. What I get is an index of the files in the folder, including index.php.

Comment: I have tried adding `/`, as well as removing `<IfModule dir_module></IfModule>`, it also seems that changing the document directory does not take effect either. I was however, able to add PHP  with additions to the httpd.conf